# i have long text i want to show as overflow text will be shown as doted in text widget in sliverlist

Tags: flutter, dart

I have facing this issue:

[image: I have facing this issue]

but I want text like this:

[image: but I want text like this]

I am working on a Flutter app and I am trying to display a long text in a SliverList widget. I want to show the overflow text as dots so that the user knows that there is more text to read. I have tried using the Text widget with the maxLines and overflow properties set, but it doesn't seem to be working in the SliverList. The text is still displayed without any truncation or dots. Can anyone help me figure out how to show the overflow text as dots in a SliverList widget in Flutter?

```
    SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth*0.05, vertical: screenHeight*0.01),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScuQGyYbgV9HFyiunO9mF6_lnB6MYwcx6t3w&usqp=CAU"),
                              radius: screenWidth*0.08,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: screenWidth*0.05,),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Adam John",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hello! my name is adam john and i'm your new tariner",
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: AppColors().darKShadowColor,
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Text(
                          "10:30pm",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color:  AppColors().darKShadowColor,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: 3,
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Text is inside a Row, so it has an unbounded width.

Wrap your Text inside an `Expanded` and also set the overflow to:

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Try to Solve Your Problem:**

```
SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth*0.05, vertical: screenHeight*0.01),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScuQGyYbgV9HFyiunO9mF6_lnB6MYwcx6t3w&usqp=CAU"),
                  radius: screenWidth*0.08,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: screenWidth*0.05,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Adam John",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        child: Text(
                          "hello! my name is adam john and i'm your new tariner",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // set overflow to ellipsis
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors().darKShadowColor,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "10:30pm",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color:  AppColors().darKShadowColor,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
 Container(
                        width: 200,//you need to set width to work overflow 
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        child: const Text(
                          "hello! my name is adam john and i'm your new tariner",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the property of overflow inside your text widget to

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

This should do the work
so this is how your container will look like

```
 Container(
                        width: 200,//you need to set width to work overflow 
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        child: const Text(
                          "hello! my name is adam john and i'm your new tariner",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        )),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            "Your Text",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```